# How to fill function arguments from slice?

Tags: sql, go

I'm new to golang, pls help a noob.

I'm trying to fill a SQL insert statement from slice of data `[]interface{}`. In order to do that I need to call Exec function of sql package with arguments which are individual parts of slice I get from input channel.

Best to show piece of code in question:

```go
// build INSERT vith variable number of columnes to fill
insertSql := "INSERT INTO " + database + "." + table + " VALUES ("
first := true
for _ = range format {
    if !first {
        insertSql += ","
    }
    first = false
    insertSql += "?"
}
insertSql += ")"

// prepare statment
stm, err := db.Prepare(insertSql)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

// execute the statement with data received via inputCh (type: []interface{})
outerLoop:
for {
    select {
        case data, opened := <-inputCh:
            if !opened {
                break outerLoop
            }

        // need to convert data of type []interface{} to individual arguments for Exec
        _, err := stm.Exec(XXXXXXX)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to append the `...` token to your slice. See the [documentation about variadic parameters](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) for more details.